# Amazon RDS SQL server and DBCC Checkdb

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, dbcc-checkdb

New Company and new to Amazon RDS. 
Several databases have been migrated to the cloud because "everything" is done for us a manager has stated.

I have explained standard DBA tasks are still required such as DBCC Checkdb, index/stats maintenance.

- Five RDS DB's
- 10GB - 20GB In size
- Mirrored within RDS

Has anyone had an issues running DBCC CheckDB on a similar setup?

I ask due to the blog post from Brent Ozar, where the job can cause the mirror to failover. 
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/sql-server-timeouts-backups-checkdb/

We have experienced this issues on an EC2 instance in the past so after anyone's experiences.

Comment: Open a support ticket and ask for guidance. Also review EBS optimized instances as they provide a secondary network adapter for communication to the EBS volumes.  Everything is going to depend on the type of instances that are running and the normal workload when you are performing those activities.

Comment: Hi Aaron is this the case with Amazon RDS, it's database as a service which I am new too so sorry for any stupid questions.

Comment: Hi @Stockburn, yes even under the hood of rds it just ec2 instances with an EBS volume and for the most part the same features and limitations apply.  The main difference with rds and you running it on your own ec2 instances is the control the os and most of the administration features of the service and they delegate access to many of the service controls just not fully. The on main difference you will find is that you can only have one volume with rds and that runs all of the database data and log files with I also believe to be tempdb.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, really helpful information I will have a dig into our setup and go from there.